# Minishift start using Hyper-v on windows 10 fails with E0113

Tags: windows-10, minishift

I am trying to run minishift on windows 10 with Hyper V but it fails with code E0113. Please find below stacktrace:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minishift start
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ... OK
-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.11.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'hyperv' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if Powershell is available ... OK
-- Checking if Hyper-V driver is installed ... OK
-- Checking if Hyper-V driver is configured to use a Virtual Switch ...
   'External VM Switch' ... OK
-- Checking if user is a member of the Hyper-V Administrators group ... OK
-- Checking the ISO URL ... OK
-- Checking if provided oc flags are supported ... OK
-- Starting the OpenShift cluster using 'hyperv' hypervisor ...
-- Starting Minishift VM ....... FAIL E0113 22:22:13.468163   19760 start.go:494] Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1. Retrying.
Error starting the VM: Error starting stopped host: exit status 1
```